# Multiplex Analog pin and digital pin on single pin

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, analog, hardware

I have to manage one single analog pin with other digital IO.
I am using a PIC micro, where I have utilized all the pins and I want one more pin for analog input. At the current stage, I can not really afford a new controller design for my project.

I have assigned 7 pins for 7 segment and the other pins are assigned to LEDs, which is a *must*.

I am looking for multiplexing circuit design (using transistor or something) where I can multiplex analog input and digital output in the design.

I will be connecting an LDR to the analog input.

Comment: it may be possible to use a LED as a light detector.

Comment: Let's see your circuit schematic. You have several options for feeding two LEDs from one GPIO. See [LED GPIO tricks](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/).

Comment: In general it is easier to multiplex multiple digital pins (input or output) then messing with an analogue pin. *"and the other pins are assigned to LEDs"* So maybe you can charlieplex your LEDs and reduce the pin count of that enough to have a dedicated analogue input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just connect both...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZVwvt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So long as you are not doing charlieplex the LDR circuitry will not be disturbed  by your LED multiplex, and the LED multiplex will not be disturbed much by the LDR.

Comment: Won't your LED switch On during high light situation?

Comment: not visibly :)  (also you only need a few microseconds to read the light level, drive the pin low when you don't want the LED.  if the LEDs are multiplexed then drive the other end high (or leave it open-circuit) when reading the brightness